# JavaScript: Cannot get @var - value out of XML-file because var is reserved?

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, openweathermap, thingworx

I am trying to get some weather data from the openweathermap-webservice. Among the data is a the iconCode too in order to visualize the current weather condition.
Here is the xml-response of the given request:

request:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=linz&units=metric&type=accurate&mode=xml&APPID=ef67184baece136977466e7894b2a614
```

one part of the response: ( i have shortened it a bit)

```
<weatherdata>
<location>...</location>
<credit/>
<meta>...</meta>
<sun rise="2017-05-30T03:07:24" set="2017-05-30T18:54:07"/>
<forecast>
  <time from="2017-05-30T09:00:00" to="2017-05-30T12:00:00">
   <symbol number="800" name="clear sky" var="02d"/>
   <precipitation/>
   <windDirection deg="223" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
   <windSpeed mps="2.31" name="Light breeze"/>
   <temperature unit="celsius" value="29.59" min="27.52" max="29.59"/>
  </time>
  <time from="2017-05-30T12:00:00" to="2017-05-30T15:00:00">
   <symbol number="800" name="clear sky" var="01d"/>
   <precipitation/>
   <windDirection deg="227.001" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
  </time>
```

I want to retrieve all iconCodes of all forecast-days. (And it works fine with the temperature, wind direction, etc...

a part of the function which should get the data from the webservice:

```
for each (var item in xmlPage.forecast.time) {
var row = new Object();
var from_current_value=item.@from.substring(0,10);

if(from_current_value!=from_today_value){
    row.WindDirection = item.windDirection.@name;
    row.WindSpeed=item.windSpeed.@mps;
    row.WeatherTemp=parseFloat(item.temperature.@value);
    row.WeatherHumidity=parseFloat(item.humidity.@value);
    row.From=item.@from;
    row.To=item.@to;
    row.Title=xmlPage.location.name+" "+xmlPage.location.country;
    row.Precipitation=(item.precipitation.@type+" "+item.precipitation.@value)==" "?"No Precipitation":item.precipitation.@type;

    var iconCode = item.symbol.@var;
    row.IconLink = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+ iconCode +".png";
```

If I have added the line var iconCode = item.symbol.@var, I get the following syntax error:

```
syntax check failed: missing name after .@ (Line#33)
```

(line33 is the "var iconCode = item.symbol.@var" line)

I think I get the error because "var" is a reserved string in JavaScript. But how do I get the iconCode from the xmlPage then? Any suggestions?

Thank you so much in advance for helping me out!
Best regards,
Theresa

Comment: Could you please [try `item.symbol['@var']` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)?

Comment: Well, should you not be able use the .getAttribute() as we do on all DOM items?  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_getattribute.asp

Answer (score 1):

According to their [documentation](http://openweathermap.org/forecast5), you should use:

> forecast.symbol.var

(in your case item.symbol.var)

Aside, using JSON might be easier?